# How to find the goals data of business case by AtTask API?

Tags: attask

I am trying to retrieve data about project management from AtTask (now called WorkFront) to generate custom report. One problem has troubled me for a whole week - ***where to retrieve data related to Goals of business case?***

What I did was to read their API document, https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/, but I failed to find it under the Project objCode.

Then I looked at the metadata which is in JSON format, and found that goals data may be in the Category/CTGY or CategoryParameter/CTGYPA, as goals are the custom data that input by users when creating a new project:

```
data: [
{ID: "ca38d71a802c453ee0440003baf6d589",
name: "DL-DLTS Form",
objCode: "CTGY",
catObjCode: "PROJ",
customerID: "ca38d7179d8f453ee0440003baf6d522",
description: "Custom data for Project Template, New Project Request and New Project creation",
enteredByID: null,
extRefID: null,
groupID: "ca38d7181120453ee0440003baf6d589",
hasCalculatedFields: false,
lastUpdateDate: "2009-05-08T14:02:30:120-0400",
lastUpdatedByID: "ca38d71802bd453ee0440003baf6d589",
otherGroups: [{ID: "ca38d7181120453ee0440003baf6d589",
name: "Default Group",
objCode: "GROUP"}],
categoryParameters: [
{objCode: "CTGYPA",
categoryID: "ca38d71a802c453ee0440003baf6d589",
displayOrder: 2,
isInvalidExpression: false,
isRequired: false,
parameterGroupID: "ca38d718d6c7453ee0440003baf6d589",
parameterID: "ca38d718d2d7453ee0440003baf6d589",
rowShared: false,securityLevel: "E"
},
{objCode: "CTGYPA",
categoryID: "ca38d71a802c453ee0440003baf6d589",
displayOrder: 1,
isInvalidExpression: false,
isRequired: true,
parameterGroupID: "ca38d718d6c7453ee0440003baf6d589",
parameterID: "ca38d718d2f8453ee0440003baf6d589",
rowShared: false, securityLevel: "E"}]}]}
```

Besides, after I looked at the HTML code of a project report where I could find the goals content, I guessed goals must be somewhere just like some other objCode as goals have ID as well:

```
<li class=" goal" data-id="53ac55e3001e83bd5ff7b289795c9d8a">
<span class="importance">Highest</span>
Ensure we still obtain the same type of report information currently provided by the BMC Coradiant TrueSight appliances. </li>
```

**Thus, all in all, where could I retrieve the data from AtTask API? Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the goals data are available in the v4.0 API, by using SCORE objCode in the API:

https://nyu.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/score/search?fields=scoreCardQuestions

**As goals are essentially the names of scoreCardQuestions!**